# This is the python code and it gives unexpected answer

Tags: python

```
school = 'Massachusetts Institute of Technology'
numVowels = 0
numCons = 0

for char in school:
if char == 'a' or char == 'e' or char == 'i' \
   or char == 'o' or char == 'u':
    numVowels += 1
elif char == 'o' or char == 'M':
    print char
else:
    numCons -= 1

print 'numVowels is: ' + str(numVowels)
print 'numCons is: ' + str(numCons)
```

This is the python code logically it should print 'o' 3 times but it doesn't i am unable to figure out why also the value of numcons should be -21 but it's coming -25 does anyone has an answer

Comment: Do you know what the `el` in `elif` means?

Comment: `or char == 'o'` prevents the `elif` condition

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't show "o" because if the character is "o", then it will trigger the first `if` statement. So instead of using `elif`, just use the `if` statement unless that isn't optimal for you.

```
if char == "o" or char == "M":
    print char
```

TL;DR: Change the `elif` to `if`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `elif` it's an `else: if`. In your case it means that if `char` is not a lower vowel and it's 'o' or 'M' it would be printed. Those are contradictory statements for 'o'. Proper condition would be

```
if char in 'aeiu': #Better use in than multiple comparisons
    numVowels += 1
elif char == 'o':
    numVowels += 1
    print(char)
elif char == 'M':
    print(char)
else:
    numCons -= 1
```

The other problem is you're only comparing against LOWER vowels, so vowels lik AEIOU will got to the `else` statement, affecting your `numCons` counter. A better code could be

```
if char.lower() in 'aeiou': #If it's vowel
    numVowels += 1
else:
    numCons -= 1

if char in 'Mo': #I think you want here the capital letter and the 'o' from 'of', char.isupper() or char == 'o' should be a better condition
    print(char)
```